# C# - Can't update quantity in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to update the quantity of a product in grid view and it doesn't update.
For example, Product A has 1 quantity currently in the shopping cart and I want to edit it to increase the quantity (e.g. 3), however after clicking update, the quantity remains 1.

Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

---

```
public static bool UpdateShopCartQuantity(int intProductID, int intQuantity)
{
    bool retStatus = false;
    // get shopping data from Session
    DataTable shoppingCartDataTable = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];

    //  Find if ProductID already exists in Shopping Cart 
    DataRow dr1 = shoppingCartDataTable.Rows.Find(intProductID);
    if (dr1 != null)
    {
        // remove item if quantity is 0
        if (intQuantity == 0)
            dr1.Delete();
        else
        {
            dr1["Quantity"] = intQuantity;
        }
        // store back shopping cart in session
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = shoppingCartDataTable;
        retStatus = true;
    }
    return retStatus;
}    

protected void gvCart_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int selectedRow = e.RowIndex;
    //get ProductID
    int productID = (int)gvCart.DataKeys[selectedRow].Value;
    //get current grid row
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvCart.Rows[selectedRow];

    TextBox tQuantity = (TextBox)row.FindControl("tbQuantity");
    int intQty = Convert.ToInt32(tQuantity.Text);
    //get shopping cart from Session
    DataTable shoppingCartDataTable = (DataTable)Session["Cart"];

    if (clsShopCart.UpdateShopCartQuantity(productID, intQty) == false)
        lblError.Text = "Update Cart fail";
    else
        lblError.Text = "Update Cart done";

    //switch to view mode
    gvCart.EditIndex = -1;
    bindGridShopCart();
    lblTotal.Text = "Total: " + clsShopCart.GetShopCartTotalPrice().ToString("C");
}
```

Comment: Is your gridview bound to session object called "cart" ?

Comment: You are calling Page.DataBind() in bindGridShopCart right?

Comment: Appreciate the help, the solution was that after calling (Page.IsPostBack == false), it is able to successfully update.